# Object 1011 has no method 'startsWith'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to categorize my product details object based on its selected product.

```
if (prodCode.startsWith("1") || prodCode.startsWith("4")) {
    ProductDetails = obj.MachineDetails;
}
else if (prodCode.startsWith("6")) {
    if (prodCode.charAt(3) == '3' || prodCode.charAt(3) == '4') {
        ProductDetails = obj.BoxDetails;
    }
    else {
        ProductDetails = obj.SomeDetails;
    }
}
else if (prodCode.startsWith("2") || prodCode.startsWith("3")) {
    ProductDetails = obj.SomeOtherDetails;
}
```

It's working fine above Android 4.4 but gives error in android 4.4:

> Object 1011 has no method 'startsWith'

`1011` is my product code.

Does anyone have any idea why its happening?

Comment: can you share the output of `console.log( String.prototype.startsWith );` and `console.log( typeof prodCode );` ?

Comment: Try startsWith Polyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

Between Android's versions, the javascript engine is not always the same and the newest features are not always available.

I encountered the same problem: you must add a polyfill before calling startsWith.

Check the polyfill section on the Mozilla page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Answer (score 0):

According to http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-String.prototype.startsWith `String.prototype.startsWith` might no be implemented in android 4.4. You can check this with using `console.log(typeof String.prototype.startsWith === 'function')`.